# rake aborted! uninitialized constant <ClassName>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Hi um quite new to rails and currently working on a task definition in rake file . This is my code

test_task.rake

```
namespace :test_name_space do
  namespace :to do
    task :my_task do
      p "========================="
      sample_out_put = SOutput.new
      sample_out_put.createfileoutput
    end
  end
end
```

and in my SOutput

```
   class SOutput



      def createfileoutput
        current_time = Time.new
        puts "====================================="
        puts "This is a scheduled file output"
        puts "====================================="
        File.open("/home/kalanamith/Desktop/out.txt", "a+") do |file|
        p current_time.inspect.to_s
        file.write("This is a sample test")
        file.write(current_time.inspect.to_s)
        end
      end


    fileoutput = SOutput.new
    fileoutput.createfileoutput
end
```

and when I run the

```
rake test_name_space:to:my_task
"========================="
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SOutput
```

um getting above error
I dont have a big picture about this error. Can anyone guide me?

```
    /home/kalanamith/Documents/rails_rnd/rails_cron/lib/tasks/test_task.rake:6:in `block (3  levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
 /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
 Tasks: TOP => test_name_space:to:my_task
```

Comment: Where's located your soutput class?

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
....
task :my_task => :environment do
....
```

Comment: still um getting the same error ** Invoke test_name_space:to:my_task (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute test_name_space:to:my_task
"========================="
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SOutput

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @eugen ah.. ok, it because i was sure that's the problem as i have it too before..

Comment: @Kalanamith can you use SOutput in rails c? maybe it wasn't loaded properly? if it's then either you need to move it to standar rails load directory (such as app) or require it first